# Test Kafka consumer using EmbddedKafka fail when launching a batch of tests

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, spring-kafka-test, embedded-kafka

I'm testing my Kafka Consumer in Spring Boot. My consumer are similar to the following

```
@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class KafkaPaymentConsumer {

    private final PaymentInterface paymentInterface;

    @KafkaListener(topics = "#{'${kafka.topic.payment}'}",
                   groupId = "#{'${kafka.group-id}'}")
    public void consumePaymentEvents(PaymentEvent paymentEvent) {
            paymentInterface.handleReceiptPaymentReceivedEvent(paymentEvent);        
    }
}
```

And My test case**s** are similar to the following

```
@SpringBootTest
@EmbeddedKafka(brokerProperties = {"listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092"},
               partitions = 1,
               controlledShutdown = true)
class KafkaPaymentConsumerTest {

    @Autowired
    KafkaTemplate<String, PaymentEvent> kafkaTemplate;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @Value("${kafka.topic.payment}")
    private String paymentTopic;


    @SpyBean
    private KafkaPaymentConsumer kafkaPaymentConsumer;

    @SpyBean
    private PaymentInterface paymentInterface;

    @Captor
    ArgumentCaptor<PaymentEvent> paymentEventCaptor;

    private static File PAYMENT_EVENT_JSON = Paths.get("src", "test", "resources", "files",
                                                       "Payment.json").toFile();
    @Test
    @SneakyThrows
    @DirtiesContext
    void consumePaymentEvents() {
        PaymentEvent event = objectMapper.readValue(PAYMENT_EVENT_JSON,
                                                    PaymentEvent.class);
        kafkaTemplate.send(paymentTopic, "1", event);

        verify(kafkaPaymentConsumer, timeout(10000).times(1)).consumePaymentEvents(
                paymentEventCaptor.capture());
        PaymentEvent argument = paymentEventCaptor.getValue();

        verify(paymentInterface, timeout(10000).times(1)).handleReceiptPaymentReceivedEvent(any());
    }
}
```

the test **works well**, BUT when running a **batch of tests** at once, some tests fail ! ( only when I run many tests at the same time !! ) it seems that there is an issue in the context with @EmbeddedKafka

I got like theses log errors

> Actually, there were zero interactions with this mock.

or a **Timeout** when trying to poll records from the broker

Any explanation or suggestion please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you don’t use a `@DirtiesContext` on your test class to close an application context in the end, it is not a surprise that other tests for the same topic can steal data from you. See if you can clean up contexts as I explained, or consider to use different topics in different tests. I’d prefer the dirties context since it guarantees that no any extra resources in the memory to cause race conditions and surprises .

Comment: I already added @DirtiesContext to Test cases, I added it to the class and I tried to change the topic names but still have the same problem !

Comment: Unless you have `spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest`, it is possible that the template sends the record before the consumer has subscribed. By default, consumers don't get records that already are in the topic (`latest` is the default).

Comment: Yeah... You see, Gary, he said that tests pass in isolation.

Comment: Still have the same issue ! that's quite strange

Comment: Any chances to share the project with us to let us to reproduce?

Comment: @ArtemBilan  you can find it here pls https://github.com/smaillns/springboot-mongo-kafka

Comment: Something is off in your config: ` value-serializer: fr.test.test.compute..config.kafka.KafkaEventSerializer`. I doubt it can start clearly with that `..` package...

Comment: Can the project be simplified without MongoDB?

Comment: You have an empty `CfrMsOverdueApplicationTests` which starts your consumers from the `main` and does not close an application context in the end. So, this one might be a culprit for "stealing" data from other tests.

Comment: it should be `value-serializer: fr.test.test.compute.config.kafka.KafkaEventSerializer`

Comment: Again: or remove that `CfrMsOverdueApplicationTests` since it is an empty `@SpringBootTest`. Or mark it with the `@DirtiesContext` as well.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `@DirtiesContext` is required but may not be sufficient. The test should also wait for the consumer to be ready, which could be done with spring-kafka-test

```
    @Autowired
    private EmbeddedKafkaBroker embeddedKafkaBroker;
    @Autowired
    private KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry;

    @BeforeEach
    void setup( ) {
        for ( MessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer : kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainers() ) {
            ContainerTestUtils.waitForAssignment( messageListenerContainer,
                                                  embeddedKafkaBroker.getPartitionsPerTopic() );
        }
    }
```